# Adobe Photoshop CS6: Where did 'preserve transparency' go?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I haven't been heavily using PhotoShop for a few years and now need to get some work done in CS6 and for the life of me, I can't find the setting for paintbrushes to 'preserve transparency' when painting on a layer.

Is this feature still there somewhere? Perhaps hidden or renamed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Preserve transparency is a layer setting. It appears at the top of the Layer Panel in the "Lock" icon list.

[image: lock]

Highlight the layer you wish to preserve and click the small checkerboard icon next to the word "Lock"

Comment: Aha! Both renamed ('lock transparent pixels') and moved! Serves me right for skipping a half dozen versions. ;)

Comment: There is also a Preserve Texture painting tool option in the Brush Panel. It's a bit different than transparency but can be very helpful.